# How to associate files with compilation command in emacs?

Tags: emacs

One thing I find myself doing a lot is every time I restart emacs, I have to retype the compilation command:

```
make XXX -f path-to-makefile/makefile
```

Sometimes I may also be working on different things at once, for example editing a .tex document and writing code, and I end up having to retype the compilation command as I switch from one to the other.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I somehow associate files with file-specific compilation commands that are known to emacs by default? Or is there some other approach that would improve my compilation workflow?

Answer (score 0):

*Sometimes I may also be working on different things at once, for example editing a .tex document and writing code, and I end up having to retype the compilation command as I switch from one to the other.*

I have written a bit of elisp to help dealing with this by defining multiple compilation commands (in the sense of `M-x`), each associated with its own buffer and shell command.

Here is the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/6130884

With this configuration, I define 4 compilation commands, which I bind to the
`<F5>`-`<F8>` keys, and I often use a workflow similar to the following:

- `<f5>` (or `M-x compile5`): associated to `make -k`
- `<f6>` (or `M-x compile6`): associated to `make -k test`
- `<f7>` (or `M-x compile7`): associated to `doxygen`

---

*every time I restart emacs, I have to retype the compilation command*

This is something I don't do much (restarting Emacs). However, take a look at
the `compile-command` variable. From the documentation (`C-h v
compile-command`):

> Last shell command used to do a compilation; default for next compilation.
>
> Sometimes it is useful for files to supply local values for this variable.

(but please also read the warning about using this as a file-local variable.